# Cannot do shipment for the order. on Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2.3.3

After Upgrade from `Magento 2.3.2` to `2.3.3` we have an error on order's shipping confirmation.

Sending `Shipping and Tracking Information` after adding any `Shipping and Tracking Information` we get blank page  `Shipped By ...`

In `system.log`

> [2019-10-23 08:42:52] main.WARNING: Broken reference: The element with
>   the "header.links" ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try again. [] []
>   [2019-10-23 08:42:52] main.WARNING: Broken reference: The element with
>   the "customer" ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try again. [] []

Anyone have a solution to fix?

Thanks,
Piero.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution of the above issue (2.3.3 - "Send Tracking Information" not working)

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25221